# Writing custom WebEx client

Tags: plugins, widget, webex

Are there API/SDK that make it possible to create custom WebEx client. So far I've only found APIs for managing pre and post-meeting content, but not during the meeting itself.

Alternatively I'd like to create a widget like plugin for WebEx. Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far a i know they do not have such API. Maybe in the future. You might want to check out other platforms such as Zoom or Talkbox

Answer (score 0):

The Webex API is currently limited to the following functionality:

User data management:

- Sign up new user (creating user accounts)
- Login/logout
- Activate/deactivate users
- Edit users

Meeting scheduling and registration:

- Schedule/host/join/impromptu
- Edit/delete
- List/add/delete attendees
- Create/get registration form
- Register attendee

Manage and access the history of online sessions:

- List/get usage history
- List recorded access history

Integrate audio conferencing networks:

- Synchronize meetings and audio conference network provisioning Adaptor-based plug-in architecture for supporting teleconferencing
  bridge equipment
- Coordinate call-in and call-out options for meeting users, and
  notification of users entering/exiting the meeting
- Support muting and dropping calls

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React then you can use these (from official webex developer account)
All of these are for different use cases so please check all of them out before using one.

1. [react-widgets](https://github.com/webex/react-widgets)
2. [webex components](https://github.com/webex/components)
3. [widgets](https://github.com/webex/widgets)

If you want to just use JS (or with any other framework) then check this one out:

- [plugin-meetings](https://github.com/webex/webex-js-sdk/tree/master/packages/node_modules/@webex/plugin-meetings) ([Npm Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@webex/plugin-meetings))

Or if you want full control over how to do things, then use webex js sdk

- [webex-js-sdk](https://github.com/webex/webex-js-sdk)